# How to place one div inside another one?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to place one div inside another one

```
<div id="test">
<img src="img/sky.jpg">
this is a test
</div>

function inner(){
var abc = document.getElementById("test");
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = abc;
}
</script>
```

It doesn't work. Is it possible at all ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild):

```
document.getElementById("main").appendChild( abc );
```

Comment: And, for thoroughness, you could demonstrate: `var main = document.getElementById('main'); main.parentNode.insertBefore(abc, main);`

Comment: @DavidThomas Why to complicate everything ?! :)

Comment: Well, you don't *have* to, or anything... =)

Comment: But where is Vincent's post. It works for me in the way I want. ThankYou.

Comment: @Alice you should edit your question if that was what you wanted. I have now done so.

Comment: trying to place one div inside another one. Where is mistake in question ?

Comment: @Alice I don't understand. The 2 answers do both completely different things and you said you wanted what Vincent's post did. And now you accepted this. Very confused :D